# I can find in a graph a path between two input nodes to be exactly of length k

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete

I have in input an undirected graph and two nodes. It is possible to find a path of lenght k, where k is a constant, in polynomial deterministic times? Or this problem belongs to NPC?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think? We're not here to solve your exercises, we're here to help you solve them yourself. Try thinking about algorithms for this problem, and in parallel try to prove that it's NP-complete; which well-known NP-hard problem is this problem similar to?

Comment: I apologize for the way I asked the question, but this problem is close to my creating problems.I know the problem Longest Path that is similar to my problem, but in Longest Path the k is not a constant.

Comment: If you suspect the problem isn't NP-hard, then it's probably in P (intermediate problems are not so easy to come up with), and you should try finding an algorithm for it which is polynomial for constant $k$ (but not necessarily for non-constant $k$, at least if you believe that your problem is difficult for non-constant $k$).

Answer (score -1):

If you could solve this in polynomial time, you could solve the longest path problem in polynomial time by checking, for each pair of nodes $u,v \in V(G)$ and each length $\ell \in \{1, \dots, |V(G)|-1\}$, whether a $uv$-path of length $\ell$ exists. Hence no poly-time algorithm for this problem exists, unless P=NP.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. Do you have a proof that longest path is NPC for fixed $\ell$?

Comment: This answer is incorrect: your reduction doesn't work, because it doesn't take into account that $k$ is a constant.  Here "constant" means that it's baked into the problem description, i.e., is a constant that does not depend on the number of vertices.  For instance, the constant might be a number like 42.  Hint: Suppose there's an algorithm for the original problem whose running time is $O(n^k)$.  Then what's the running time of your proposed algorithm for the longest path problem?

Comment: I'm not certain what the OP meant, but I interpreted it as meaning the algorithm takes the graph and $k$ as input (as opposed to simply taking a graph and producing a path of some arbitrary length $k$). I agree that if he actually means that the $k$ is fixed even within the algorithm that my reduction doesn't work.